# ProGuard cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in snowplow-android-tracker library

Tags: android, proguard

Our Android app receives `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with the following error message when using ProGuard and snowplow library [0]:

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime(10137): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-573
E/AndroidRuntime(10137): Process: com.appier.tracker.android.demo, PID: 10137
E/AndroidRuntime(10137): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <clinit> failed for class com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.tracker.android.Util; see     exception in other thread    
E/AndroidRuntime(10137):        at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.tracker.android.Subject$1.run(Unknown Source)    
E/AndroidRuntime(10137):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)    
E/AndroidRuntime(11486):     FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-753    
E/AndroidRuntime(11486):     Process: com.appier.tracker    .android.demo, PID: 11486    
E/AndroidRuntime(11486):     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundEr    ror: <clinit> failed for class com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.tracker.android.Util; see     exception in other thread    
E/AndroidRuntime(11486):    at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.tracker.android.Subject$1.run(Unknown Source)    
E/AndroidRuntime(11486):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
--------- beginning of system
```

However, we set ProGuard to keep `com.snowplowanalytics.**` via the following setting in `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn com.snowplowanalytics.**
-keep class com.snowplowanalytics.**{
   *;
}
```

To ensure the ProGuard get the correct configuration, we use baksmali [1] to verify if ProGuard keeps `Util` or not. The following is head of `Util.smali` generated by `baksmali`:

```
.class public Lcom/snowplowanalytics/snowplow/tracker/android/Util;
.super Lcom/snowplowanalytics/snowplow/tracker/core/Util;


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .registers 1

    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/snowplowanalytics/snowplow/tracker/core/Util;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method

.method public static getAdvertisingID(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;
    .registers 2

    invoke-static {p0}, Lcom/snowplowanalytics/snowplow/tracker/android/Util;->getPlayAdId(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/    lang/String;    

    move-result-object v0

    return-object v0
.end method

.method private static getAdvertisingInfoObject(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    .registers 7

....
```

Since `Util` still has all its symbol names, the ProGuard indeed read the configuration and keep `com.snowplowanalytics.**`. However, Android still cannot find the class and throw `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. We are not sure what we miss, so please advise us how to do next to let snowplow library and ProGuard work together without any problem, thanks.

[0] https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow-android-tracker/releases/tag/0.2.0

[1] https://code.google.com/p/smali/